# How to include new line "\n" in PHP regex match

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex as follows:

```
$regex = '/(https?\:\/\/|www)[^(\"|\\\) ]+/i';
```

Which I want to extract just the url from the following:

```
Here is some dummy text http://testwebsite.com.eu\n\nIf you don't like this dummy text then tough luck.
```

My result returns

```
http://testwebsite.com.eu

If
```

How can I change my regex so it includes the \n in its search?

Edit - a link to my regex101 query works. But when trying to implement in php it doesn't. Please note I am running the php through CLI. https://regex101.com/r/lNovMJ/1

Comment: by adding  /[\r\n]/

Comment: In regex, the cariage return is represented by `\r`

Comment: What is purpose `[^(\"|\\\) ]+` in your regex?

Comment: @anubhava it is to stop when there is a " or a \ or a space

Comment: Double quotes and colons don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex to make it work:

```
~\b(?:https?://|www)[^"\\\s]+~
```

`\s` inside negated character class will stop matching when we encounter any whitespace (including newlines).

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC0MFh/10)

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression

```
/\r\n?|\n/
```

matches all three types of newlines, namely `\n` on Linux, `\r\n` on Windows and `\r` on Mac.